# WAMP Server Your Projects urls are invalid & do n't work

Tags: windows-7, wampserver

I installed latest **x64** wamp server :  `wampserver3.1.0_x64.exe` On **Windows 7**.
I changed it's default 80 port to 8080, because of IIS & now every thing is ok.
I added a simple project to this path : `C:\wamp64\www` like below :

> C:\wamp64\www\php_test\index.php

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Now when i go to this path `http://localhost:8080/` > Your Projects Area > 
php_test > It's link is like this > `http://php_test:8080/` > That does not work & is invalid.
The true link is :  `http://localhost:8080/php_test`
How can i fix this problem?
I found the link below for that :
[Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server)
I followed the answer.
Now the new problem is after adding virtual hosts, `phptest` does not work again.
Here is `httpd-vhosts.conf` file :

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName phptest
    DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/php_test"
    <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/php_test/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I did restart all services after adding `phptest` to virtual hosts.

---

My questions :
 1.  How can i fix that invalid link?
 2.  How make virtual hosts workable?

---

**EDIT After Comments** > Here is my HOSTS file content :

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
#
#
```

Comment: Did you see the link on the Tools menu of the WAMPServer homepage called "Add a Virtual Host". Follow that and it will help you create a Virtual host correctly.

Comment: Did you amend your HOSTS file to include this new "phptext" domain name?

Comment: What change is necessary in HOSTS file?

Comment: Well show us your hosts file and someone may be able to tell you. Please add that to your question, dont post it as a comment

Comment: I edit my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HOSTS file is basically empty as a `#` is a comment.

You have to add a reference to each VHOST into your HOSTS file like this so that the browser can find your development domains

Hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1       localhost
127.0.0.1 phptest
::1       phptest
```

Now you must restart the DNS Cache like this, from a command prompt that you have started "As an Administrator" or just reboot the PC

```
>net stop dnscache
```

When that has completed do

```
>net start dnscache
```

Or there is a menu item on WAMPServers menus

```
[Right Click] wampmanager-> Tools -> Restart DNS
```